# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0 after update ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, docker

After installed updates on ubuntu I have problem with build project.
When I run mvn clean install there are error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project spring-petclinic-customers-service: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/sicio/test/spring-petclinic-microservices/spring-petclinic-customers-service/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/sicio/test/spring-petclinic-microservices/spring-petclinic-customers-service && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/sicio/test/spring-petclinic-microservices/spring-petclinic-customers-service/target/surefire/surefirebooter1048453915443824886.jar /home/sicio/test/spring-petclinic-microservices/spring-petclinic-customers-service/target/surefire 2018-11-20T21-01-40_588-jvmRun1 surefire6900955508880771947tmp surefire_0182883786028713736tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/sicio/test/spring-petclinic-microservices/spring-petclinic-customers-service && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/sicio/test/spring-petclinic-microservices/spring-petclinic-customers-service/target/surefire/surefirebooter1048453915443824886.jar /home/sicio/test/spring-petclinic-microservices/spring-petclinic-customers-service/target/surefire 2018-11-20T21-01-40_588-jvmRun1 surefire6900955508880771947tmp surefire_0182883786028713736tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Before I installed updates everything  works fine. I reinstalled docker but nothing changed.
Version docker: Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
In docker-compose.yml are entrypoint like:

```
entrypoint: ["./dockerize","-wait=tcp://config-server:8888","-timeout=60s","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Maybe someone have same problem and can help me.